# QGraphicsBlurEffect resizes Text but not Widget itself

Tags: c++, macos, qt, blur, qt5.5

I'm trying to use Qt 5.5.1 [`QGraphicsBlurEffect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsblureffect.html) in my project, but can't make it work on Mac:

[image: screenshot on mac]

I was trying to make a change by using `PerformanceHint`, `QualityHint` or `AnimationHint`, but didn't succeed. Using `QGraphicsColorizeEffect` I had the same issue, while `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` and  `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect`, as well as everything on Linux worked perfectly fine:

[image]

How can I change my project file or code to make this graphics issue go away? Is it even possible?

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT += widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;

    QTextEdit *text = new QTextEdit;
    text->setReadOnly(true);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(text);

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
    widget->setLayout(layout);

    QGraphicsBlurEffect effect;
    effect.setBlurRadius(3);

    QLabel *test = new QLabel("TEST");
    test->setGraphicsEffect(&effect);
    (new QHBoxLayout(text))->addWidget(test, 0, Qt::AlignCenter);

    window.setCentralWidget(widget);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Are you using a HDPI/Retina display? Looks like the font is exactly scaled by factor 2? My *guess* would be that its a bug caused by retina (devicePixelRatio=2) not handled correctly.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I think so. But it's the same with images in a `QLabel`. Do you have an idea how to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with `QGraphicsOpacityEffect`: blurred text and icons when it must be crisp sharp. Seems like a bug in Qt. My solution was to write my own small class containing everything I need with a proper rendering.
Well, you can try to fix Qt... good luck at reading source code of graphics effects. It is quite complicated with all it's dpr and transform matrix and rendering child widgets.

Comment: I indeed read it already. Would you mind to share your code here? Maybe a simplified version which could reproduce the fix.

Comment: With opacity it was easy. Because `QPainter` has a `setOpacity()` function. So I could override `QWidget::paintEvent()` and make my own painting logic using painter with proper opacity. You may change opacity through some custom property and call `QWidget::update()`. The result is pretty nice in animations.
I'm afraid with blur effect it won't be so easy solution.